# Testing a redux action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs, redux-thunk

I am trying to implement jest with our redux actions. Given the below action foo and it's following test, the following test is failing because `store.getActions()` is only returning me `[{"type": "ACTION_ONE"}]` as supposed to `[{"type": "ACTION_ONE"}, {"type": "ACTION_TWO"}]`. How do I get both dispatched actions when testing? Thanks!

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

export const foo = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(actionOne());
    return HttpService.get(`api/sampleUrl`)
      .then(json => dispatch(actionTwo(json.data)))
      .catch(error => handleError(error));
  };
};

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);

beforeEach(() => {
  store = mockStore({});
});

describe('sample test', () => {
  test('validates foo complex action', () => {
    const expectedActions = [
      {type: actionTypes.ACTION_ONE},
      {type: actionTypes.ACTION_TWO},
    ];

    return store.dispatch(actions.foo())
      .then(() => {
        expect(store.getActions())
          .toEqual(expectedActions);
      });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't mocked the API call and since it won't success without a mock, the action dispatched when the promise resolves is not fired. You can use `fetchMock` to mock the API call. Once you do that correctly, your test will work

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

export const foo = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(actionOne());
    return fetch(`api/sampleUrl`)
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(json => dispatch(actionTwo(json)))
      .catch(error => handleError(error));
  };
};

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);

beforeEach(() => {
  store = mockStore({});
  fetchMock.restore()
});

describe('sample test', () => {
  test('validates foo complex action', () => {

    fetchMock.getOnce('api/sampleUrl', {
      body: { sample: ['do something'] }
    })

    const expectedActions = [
      {type: actionTypes.ACTION_ONE},
      {type: actionTypes.ACTION_TWO},
    ];

    return store.dispatch(actions.foo())
      .then(() => {
        expect(store.getActions())
          .toEqual(expectedActions);
      });
  });
});
```